# Laravel Controller configuration for statistic website

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am designing a website with the Laravel platform (5.7) and I need your help.

I have a table with the name 'tblmatches'.  The relevant fields in the table are:

P1_ID (Winner)

P2_ID (Loser)

Year (Year)

I want to create controller that will be able to calculate the total number of player wins and losses for any specified year.

I have the following function working without any reference to the Year field.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $Play = Play::find($id);
    // $Wins = 15;
    $Wins = DB::table('tblmatches')
    ->where('P1_ID', $id)
     ->count();

     $Losses = DB::table('tblmatches')
    ->where('P2_ID', $id)
     ->count();

     $WinPercentage = ($Wins / ($Wins + $Losses)) * 100;


    return view('Players.gauge')->with('Play', $Play)->with('Wins', $Wins)->with('Losses', $Losses)->with('WinPercentage', $WinPercentage);
}
```

Eventually, I will want the ability to view all of the player results simultaneously to see which player has the best win/loss record.

Any suggestions would be helpful for me.

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a request website.

Comment: Sorry Aken, I have edited the question to show what I currently have working.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this in your controller

```
public function calculateWinner(){
   $winners=tblmatches::where('P1_ID','year')->get();
   foreach($winners as $winner){

    $winner_count+=$winner->winner;

  }
}
```

please post you database table so as to edit this better, thanks

Comment: P1 always is winner and P2 always is loser?